# calculation of permutation sequence

Tags: c++, algorithm

I am working on below problem and post code I am debugging and the problem statement. Actually I tried to find a few reference solutions, and all are similar without too much explanation. If anyone could help to explain how below logic works, it will be great. I am confused especially by the loop of "for(i=0,k--;i

```
The set [1,2,3,…,n] contains a total of n! unique permutations.

By listing and labeling all of the permutations in order,
We get the following sequence (ie, for n = 3):

"123"
"132"
"213"
"231"
"312"
"321"
Given n and k, return the kth permutation sequence.

Note: Given n will be between 1 and 9 inclusive.
```

Code reference,

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

string getPermutation(int n, int k) {
    int i,j,f=1;
    // left part of s is partially formed permutation, right part is the leftover chars.
    string s(n,'0');
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++){
        f*=i;
        s[i-1]+=i; // make s become 1234...n
    }
    for(i=0,k--;i<n;i++){
        f/=n-i;
        j=i+k/f; // calculate index of char to put at s[i]
        char c=s[j];
        // remove c by shifting to cover up (adjust the right part).
        for(;j>i;j--)
            s[j]=s[j-1];
        k%=f;
        s[i]=c;
    }
    return s;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    // insert code here...
    std::cout << getPermutation(4, 5) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Post another implementation which is more clear to read,

```
def kthperm(S, k):  #  nonrecursive version
    P = []
    while S != []:
        f = factorial(len(S)-1)
        i = int(floor(k/f))
        x = S[i]
        k = k%f
        P.append(x)
        S = S[:i] + S[i+1:]
    return P
```

Comment: For how it works you could try https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial_number_system or http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/60742/finding-the-n-th-lexicographic-permutation-of-a-string.

Comment: `for(i=0,k--;i<n;i++)` is equivalent to `k--; for(i=0; i<n; i++)`, if that helps. It's just more obscure.

Comment: @AlanStokes, much clear now after reading your reference. My last confusion is, why we need below logics? `// remove c by shifting to cover up (adjust the right part).
        for(;j>i;j--)
            s[j]=s[j-1];`

Comment: @AlanStokes, post another implementation which is more clear to read, from the link you referred. Thanks.

Comment: In the time before The Internet I posted this algorithm to Software Development Magazine (later assimilated into Dr Dobbs), implemented in Modula-2. I thought it was possibly new, it was certainly not mentioned by Knuth. But the editor added a comment that it was invented by a Texas Instruments engineer. Not sure how to access old SDJ readers comments. But as I recall the editor added the title "The third method's the charm" (referring to the two methods for permutations discussed by Knuth).

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf, do you mean the new method I posted if the 3rd methods?

Comment: I mean the general idea, as expressed by the Python code. Not sure if the C++ implementation is correct. Instead of shifting I used a bitset, but in terms of big O performance that doesn't buy anything (it just moves the complexity around).

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf, thanks for the comments! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem statement asks for the Kth permutation of N elements, in the *lexical* ordering of the permutations.

The code implements a very nice algorithm that generates the elements of the Kth permutation directly, in order, like this (pseudo-code):

```
GenerateKthPermutation(Set elements, int k)
{
    if (elements.size()==1)
    {
       output(elements.getOnlyElement());
       return;
    }
    int n = elements.size();

    //there are n! permutations of elements
    //no matter which one we choose as the _first_ element, there
    //will be (n-1)! permutations of the remaining elements.
    //The complete lexical ordering of permutations consists of:
    //(n-1)! permutations that start with the smallest element, then
    //(n-1)! permutations that start with the second smallest element, then
    //(n-1)! permutations that start with the 3rd smallest element, etc.
    //so the FIRST element in the (0-indexed) kth permutation, is the
    //(0-indexed) floor(k/(n-1)!)th-largest element

    int j = floor((k-1)/(n-1)!); //k-1, because the parameter is 1-indexed
    //removeJthLargest(0) removes and returns the smallest element
    //removeJthLargest(1) removes and returns the second-smallest
    //etc.
    output(elements.removeJthLargest(j));

    //now output the correct permutation of remaining elements.
    //we've skipped j*(n-1)! permutations, so subtract that from k
    k -= j*(n-1)!;

    //remember elements is 1 smaller now.
    //in real life you would iterate here instead of recursing
    GenerateKthPermutation(elements, k);
}
```

I hope that makes things clear.  To specifically answer your question in comments:

The original logic uses a sorted string to store the set of elements.  the part that says "remove c by shifting..." is the part where I say "elements.removeJthLargest(j)".  It removes the proper element from the string and shifts the remaining ones to make a new, smaller, but still-sorted string.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I posted a non-recursive algorithm implementation, do you think it is a better solution? :)

Comment: It's the same algorithm.  I just wrote it recursively here so that it would be easier to understand.  If I was putting this into a product, I would have used a loop instead.  The C++ and python versions you posted are both good implementations.